# Preferred way for data: json or sqlite

Tags: json, sqlite

I want to know what the normal/preferred way of working is.

The iOS app needs data. This can come from an included sqlite db, or via an online json feed.
What is the normal way of working?
Use the sqlite db and update that based on json feed? 
Or skip the db, only use json?

Comment: If you want to persist the data you should use Core Data. You can either ship a pre-filled database with your app or initialize it from a local or remote JSON file at the first start. If you don't need persistence you typically load some JSON contents into NSDictionaries and NSArrays.

Comment: Someone removed the Xcode tag (that is correct, this question is not related to Xcode at all) but you should add an Objective-C tag.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on a few things.

- If your data is going to be static (read-only) you probably will want to use json.
- If you only have a small amount of data, you may want to look into `NSUserDefaults`
- If your data is going to be changing quite a bit, then you may want to look into either SQLite (maybe have a look at FMDB) or CoreData (and I would suggest looking at MagicalRecord).

Comment: For the moment i'm using SQLite with FMDB. Data would be product catalog, so that needs to be updated. So the preferred way is update db from json in the application load? Do you store a version number in the db to check of there is an update? OR, place a new sqlite db online somewhere, and replace the current db in documents folder with the new one?